# Modulus Distributing Over Multiplication?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Given positive integers a,b,c and k:

Define a function $M: \mathbb{Z^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ as

$$M(x,y) = (x \bmod y)$$

i.e. the remainder of integer division

The following is always true:

$$a+b=c \implies M(M(a,k) + M(b,k), k) = M(c,k)$$

Under which values of k is the following true:

$$ab=c \implies M(M(a,k)M(b,k), k) = M(c,k)$$

That is when does mod distribute over multiplication?

The answer is always:

**Proof**:

Let $a = q_ak + r_a$ and $b = q_bk + r_b$ where $ 0 \le r_a, r_b < k$

$$\begin{align*}
c &= ab \\
&= (q_ak + r_a)(q_bk + r_b) \\
&= q_aq_bk^2 + q_ar_bk + q_br_ak + r_ar_b \\
&= (q_aq_bk + q_ar_b + q_br_a)k + r_ar_b \\
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
M(c,k) &= M((q_aq_bk + q_ar_b + q_br_a)k + r_ar_b,k) \\
&= M(r_ar_b,k)
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
M(M(a,k)M(b,k), k) &=(M(q_ak + r_a,k)M(q_bk + r_b,k)) \\
&= M(r_ar_b, k)
\end{align*}$$

QED

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** [$\rm\ mod\ k\!:\ A\equiv a,\, B\equiv b\:\Rightarrow\: AB\equiv ab,\ $](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23798/242) so $\rm\ AB\, mod\, k\, =\, ab\, mod\, k$

Yours is the special case $\rm\ A = (a\,mod\,k),\,\ B = (b\,mod\,k)$

Comment: So the answer is always.  So whats the big deal about having a prime base then?  Its just having a modular inverse for everything?

Comment: @user1131467 Yes. A prime modulus (not base) is not needed for this. But it is needed if you desire that there exist multiplicative inverses of all elements $\not\equiv 0.$

Comment: I tried to prove the answer and added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @user1131467 Yes, you can also do it that way using only remainders, though it is clearer using congruences as above.